# Are there changes in garbage collection in .NET 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, .net-4.5

Are there changes in garbage collection in .NET 4.5 ?

the change from 3.5 to 4.0 was tremendous for low-latency apps.. are there anything like that coming in 4.5 ?

the information about 4.5 is really scarce on the internet... i hope someone could know more...

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/10/04/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Large Object Heap Improvements in .NET 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2011/10/04/large-object-heap-improvements-in-net-4-5.aspx) *(Brandon Bray, MSDN blogs)*